# How to use a typo3 constant in an href?

Tags: typo3

To make things easier, I can define the main url of my page as a constant in a template: `tx_dti.settings.url = https:/someserver/`

Now I like to use this constant in my text element to link an internal page eg:
`<a href="{tx_dti.settings.url}?id=13" class="internal-link">Contact Form</a>`

Unfortunately my above mentioned approach does not work.
**What is the correct syntax to replace the server with a constant?**
The goal is that I only want to change the constant when I move from a dev to a productive server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**in general:**
You can not use typoscript constants outside typoscript templates (constants and setup). If you want to use the value of a typoscript constant in other context you need to transfer the value.

If you want to use the constant in fluid you need to transfer the value to a fluid variable.

```
temp.content = FLUIDTEMPLATE
temp.content {
    template = ...
    variables {
        domain = TEXT
        domain.value = {$myTSconstant}
        :
    }
}
```

or

```
settings { 
    domain = TEXT
    domain.value = {$myTSconstant}
    :
}
```

If you want to use the constant in a data field of a content element you might use a marker and replace the marker with typoscript as last step of rendering.

```
"<p>This is my text and here I use a marker: __MYMARKER__</p>"
```

the corresponding typoscript:

```
page {
    :

    stdWrap.replacement {
         1.search = __MYMARKER__
         1.replace = {$myTSconstant}
    }
}
```

Note:
always use TS constants with a `$` before the name inside the curly braces.
Don't confuse it with variable usage in fluid (without `$`).

**regarding your problem:**
as Riccardo mentioned: don't use constants for your links, even: **don't build your links by hand**. If you really need your domain in urls, automate it with a setting of `config.absRefPrefix` (preferrable to `config.baseURL`)

Comment: "don't build your links by hand", ok. So if I have a content page e.g. a user wants to point to a contact form -> <a href="https://myserver/?id=13" class="internal-link">Contact Form</a>
How would I build this, I would like to follow the best practice rule. Would that be to use the above config.* vars? If so how would that given href from above look like?
If this is too basic, i'd be happy to get a link where I can help my self.

Comment: in content fields where you can use links you have the RTE (Rich Text Editor) with the option to link marked text. this will start a link wizard, where you select your link target. this wizard will build an a-tag in the content, but it's done with automated logic and uses defined syntax to be computed automatically afterwards. This link also will be considered if you have configured `config.absRefPrefix` or use realurl.

Comment: To recap: when I use the link wizrad of the RTE it currently generates a link as like <a href="http://devserver:8081/?id=13" class="internal-link" title="Opens internal link in current window">Texte</a>. In my template I have set: tx_dti.settings.url = https:/someserver/
Since this setting is not reflected I assume I need to set somewhere config.baseURL = tx_dti.settings.url ?

Comment: If TYPO3 renders a link it considers every active configuration for it. that include the config values (mainly `absRefPrefix` and `baseURL` for the URL and also configs like `intTarget` and `extTarget` for automatic target parameter, but also extensions like realurl which modify the URL to a human readable format). If you modify the generated syntax or do links by hand this might not be considered as TYPO3 might not detect a link to handle.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you could use `config.absRefPrefix` or `config.baseURL` (see https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Config/)

you can set in TypoScript constants:

```
tx_dti.settings.url = http://myserver
```

then in TypoScript Setup:

```
config.baseURL = {$tx_dti.settings.url}
```

or

```
config.absRefPrefix = {$tx_dti.settings.url}
```

Is this sufficient or am I misunderstanding your request?

Comment: Assuming I have set the above mentioned config vars. How would I make use of it in my html code? How would a RELATIVE Link look like in this url??
<a href="http://myserver/id=13" class="internal-link">Contact Form</a>

Comment: If we are talking of links inside some text added using the Rich Text Editor (or CKEditor if you use TYPO3 8.7), as Bernd Wilke said on a previous request, you have to select the page with the form in the wizard, and the link syntax will adjust itself automatically (including the absRefPrefix or baseURL that will be automatically prepended.